# When calling isActive() on window while dragging/resizing it, false returns. (X11, Qt 5.4.0)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, pyqt, x11

I'm using Qt 5.4.0 on linux (X11) and I need to determine, if my window is active. So, I wrote example code, given below. If that code compiled on windows, it logs "false" in console only when window isn't really active. But on linux (X11), it also logs "false" when I start to drag or resize window. Why this happen and how to fix that on linux? I want to know, when my window is really inactive, and when it's active, but being dragged/resized.

code snippet (C++):

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e) {
    if (e->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange) {
        if (this->isActiveWindow()) {
            std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

same code, on PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class TransparentWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TransparentWidget, self).__init__()

    def changeEvent(self, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.ActivationChange:
            print(self.isActiveWindow())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    transparent_widget = TransparentWidget()
    transparent_widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The exact behaviour probably depends on your WM. Why do you think it needs fixing?

Comment: At first, I can reproduce this on multiple VMs, such as KDE (Kwin), Unity (Compiz), XFCE. I guess this behaviour isn't proper. And, next, same program running on Windows and OS X works normally, saying that window is active, when I drag or resize it. That's what for Qt is created: programm behaves same on different platforms and that's why that should be fixed. Our team also reported that in bugtracker.

Comment: There seems to be no obvious work-around for this, because the resize/move event always happens *after* the activation change.

Comment: @BOOtak. It would be helpful if you could put a link to the Qt bug report in your question.

Comment: So this must be a Qt5 thing because I cannot reproduce this with Qt 4.8 (I don't have Qt5 installed). This is rather strange, as `isActive()` ought to just tell whether your window has focus. This is not under the control of Qt in any way, it just reports the status. Anyway I remain with my opinion that you are doing something wrong, regardless of what Qt should or should not do.

Comment: @n.m. It's obviously a Qt5 bug. The OP is not doing anything wrong: with PyQt5 on Linux (X11), the behaviour is easily reproduced. The real issue is that Qt5 sends an `ActivationChange` event at the start and end of a resize/move, and `isActiveWindow()` returns `True` at the end, but `False` at the start. For Qt4, this is all moot, because it doesn't send any `ActivationChange` events at all during a resize/move. (Disclaimer: I have only tested this on one Linux system, so YMMV).

Comment: @ekhumoro "is not doing anything wrong" is trying to dictate when the window should or should not be active, instead of just reacting to events.

Comment: @n.m. But the OP **is** just reacting to events (I have no idea what you mean by "trying to dictate"). The problem is that Qt5 is posting bogus events. Resizing or moving a window does not constitute an activation change.

Comment: @ekhumoro "Resizing or moving a window does not constitute an activation change" perhaps it does, perhaps it does not. A window system may behave either way, there's no reason why it couldn't. If your design depends on it, it is probably wrong.

Comment: @n.m. Qt4 and Qt5 behave differently for the **same window manager** on the **same platform**. Clearly, they can't *both* be right, hence there is a bug in either Qt4 or Qt5 (almost certainly the latter). It is ridiculous to claim that code cannot depend on the documented behaviour (whatever it may be) - without such guarantees we might as well all give up and go and play golf or something.

Comment: "can't both be right" depends on how you define right. "depend on the documented behaviour" that would be OK but is it really documented? where?

Comment: @n.m. No, it only ever depends on what the window manager actually does. Qt must passively report whatever information is made available to it. On X11, the active window is whichever one could currently take input focus (if any). As with most other platforms, this is most commonly indicated by a change in the titlebar colour. However, just because a window is currently active, it doesn't necessarily mean it will, in fact, receive or accept keyboard input. Qt4 and Qt5 are interpreting the same information about window activation changes differently - which is, at the very least, inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

It probably registers 'false' because on X the window you see is actually two windows: the window where you paint your contents and a slighly larger window, which is the parent window of yours and contains the border.

The reason is that X11 doesn't have a concept of a "decorated border" with close/max/min buttons, titlebar, nice gradient colors, rounded borders etc. (native X11 windows can have a border, but only as a solid color or texture). Those controls are provided by your window manager. What happens is that if you create a window, the window manager creates an extra X11 window which is slightly larger than yours and places your window as a child on this new window. From then on, the two windows are intimately linked: resizing your window will resize the parent window and vice versa.

This is all handled by the window manager. For example, if you want to resize  the window and click on the border, the click goes not to your window but to the window manager, which then determines where the click was and decides what to do with it. So at that moment your own window is not active anymore, which explains why isActiveWindow() returns false.

With Microsoft Windows the border is an integral part of the window itself, so that's why it remains 'active'.

Anyway, to find out if your window is 'active' or not, you should use the QFocusEvent. By looking at the gotFocus() and lostFocus() values you should be able to track when you window is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

The active window is the window that currently accepts the keyboard input focus, and therefore is also the window to which keyboard events are sent.

During a resize/move operation, the active window does not register keyboard events (whether they are actually sent or not). Given this, it is arguable whether the window should still be regarded as active during such operations.

Qt4 and Qt5 differ in how they deal with this. Qt4 does not report window activation changes (or focus changes) during a resize/move on any platform (I only actually tested on X11 and Windows, though). The same is also true for Qt5 - except when it comes to X11.

On X11, Qt5 reports a window activation change (and a focus change) at the start and end of all resize/move operations. That is, `isActiveWindow()` returns `False` when the operation starts and `True` when it ends (and the corresponding `FocusIn/FocusOut` events are also sent, as well as `WindowActivate/WindowDeactivate` events, and so forth).

It could be argued that the Qt5 behaviour on X11 is the only one that is accurate. However, it is inconsistent with the other platforms Qt5 supports, and so from a developer's point of view it must be considered buggy (or at the very least, inconvenient).

Although the behaviour on Qt4 is arguably less acccurate, it is at least consistent across all the platforms it supports (i.e. it is exactly what a developer would expect from a cross-platform toolkit).

Unfortunately, the resize/move events only begin *after* the window activation changes, so there does not seem to be any obvious way to filter out the unwanted activation events in Qt5.

Comment: I agree that Qt5 behaviour on X11 platform is accurate, but I used isActive() method to determine if my window is foreground. So. probably, Qt developers should add some other method, such as isForeground() for this purposes. I will find work-around by calling native X11 API methods to find foreground window and will post it here.